# Win Api (LONG в C++ (long или int))

Tags: c++, winapi, типы-данных, конвертация

Нам дали изучать win api (хотя хз зачем он вообще в текущих реалиях нужен)...
Сабж, функция возвращает структуру с типом  LONG (в полях, winapi), нужно его привести к обычному типу long, а лучше вообще int.  Как это сделать не знаю, в гугле ничего внятного не нашел, а спросить не у кого. Прошу помочь.

Comment: sizeof + компилятор с любимым текстовым редактором помогут вам

Comment: эм, можно подробнее, с++ изучали год назад, больше не затрагивали, меня этот LONG беспокоит, я не знаю что с ним делать, можно пример?

Comment: unsigned long foo = (unsigned long)LONG_var

Comment: Если можете, выкиньте вы вообще эту винду с ее тяжким наследством. А вообще -- берете и пробуете -- sizeof даст размер, сравнение -1 с 0-м этого типа -- signed или unsigned

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос-то? Целочисленные типы в С и С++ обычно свободно (неявно) приводятся друг к другу. То есть фактически "вообще ничего не надо делать". Потому и в гугле ничего не нашлось. В чем затруднение-то?

Comment: "хотя хз зачем он вообще в текущих реалиях нужен". Что, интересно, имеется в виду? Что вы будете везде использовать, к примеру, Qt и не сталкиваться с голым системным API вообще? Такие заявления сродни "зачем в текущих реалиях нужно знание ассемблера". Представьте себе, нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, обычно в Windows имя `LONG` определяется как

```
typedef long LONG;
```

То есть имя `LONG` определяется как алиас для некоторого стандартного арифметического типа.

Так что вы можете присваивать значение объекта типа `LONG` объекту типа `long`.

А также можете присваивать значение объекта типа `LONG` объекту типа `int`  (хотя такое присвоение может говорить о том, что, возможно, вы что-то делаете неправильно) при условии, что нет потери значимости числа. Компилятор может выдать предупреждение при таком присваивании. Чтобы его избежать, вам следует использовать явное приведение типов. Например,

```
LONG x = 10;
int y;

y = ( int )x;

// или

y = static_cast<int>( x );
```